# What's the job of Jordan Belfort's father?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-wolf-of-wall-street

I thought at the beginning, Jordan says he came from a family of both his parents being accountants, however later it appears that Jordan's Father is an ex-Cop and a PI?

Comment: The movie did in fact say he was an accountant which is why he went to work for Jordan. CAn you explain the scene(s) that made you think he was/is a PI?

Comment: Doesn't he outright say he had his PI license and was an ex-Cop in the same scene that they talk about women and "liking bush"? The same scene that Jordan bites on his knuckles? And his father was the one who tipped him off about being under observation by the FBI and also about Brad being arrested.

Comment: You sure you're not thinking of Bo Dietl (the P.I.) who played him self? I believe he was the one who told Jordan Brad was in jail right before those old pills kicked in at the country club. The two do look alike.

Comment: It seems that I did think they were the same person

Comment: In all fairness they do look VERY similar!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Max Belfort "Mad Max" was an accountant. The person who tipped Jordan off about the FBI and told him about Brad being in jail because of Donnie was Bo Dietl who looks like Max. So no, Jordan's father was not an ex-cop or P.I. but Bo Dietl was.

They look VERY similar

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow, they even have the same grin.

Answer (score 0):

Belfort's father Max, was to "Maintain order" in the chaos they had going at the firm. It was a free-for-all, with sex/drugs/money/testosterone going full steam. Think Sodom and Gomorrah, and Max was the cop trying to keep things from getting too far out of hand, more like a way to keep them connected to the rest of the world. Remember the scene where they discuss EJ entertainment? He had to try to keep everyone balanced out.